# Error al obtener el ultimo id - django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Actualmente estoy realizando una app web con Django 1.11.18 En el campo `id` tengo un método auto incrementable que empieza desde un numero dado, pero al llegar a 1000, no sigue sumando, el `id` se queda en el 1000.

Este es el método:

```
def incremento_id_orden():
    id = 641
    cant_id = Orden_cargue.objects.count()
    if cant_id == 0:
        return id
    else:
        num_id = Orden_cargue.objects.latest('num_orden')
        print(num_id)
        nue = str(num_id)
        print(nue)
        aj = int(nue)
        print(aj)
        nuevo_id = aj + 1
        print(nuevo_id)
        return nuevo_id
```

Y este es el campo del modelo:

```
 num_orden = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, default=incremento_id_orden, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django delega el ordenamiento a la base de datos, obtener el último elemento depende del tipo de dato, es decir, para números enteros el último elemento es el número más grande, para cadenas el último elemento es el elemento lexicográficamente mayor (puedes revisar la [documentacion oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#latest)).

El problema radica en que estas utilizando un tipo de dato `CharField` que es una cadena, cuando tratas de obtener el último elemento con la función `latest` estas obteniendo el objeto con el campo `num_order` lexicográficamente mayor, es decir dada la siguiente lista: `'641', ..., '997', '998', '999'` el valor lexicográfico mayor seria `'999'`, sin embargo en la lista `'641', ..., '997', '998', '999', '1000'` el máximo valor lexicográfico sigue siendo `'999'` y no `'1000'` como seguramente estas esperando.

La solución debería ser el uso de un tipo de dato numérico, para este caso sería cambiar `CharField` por `IntegerField`

```
num_orden = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=incremento_id_orden, editable=False)
```